# Python - Alarm clock with multiple alarms

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an alarm clock with multiple alarms, which are set from a text file with a specific time each line, but at the moment it's only working if I set only one time. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code I have right now:

```
import time
from playsound import playsound

Time = time.strftime('%H:%M')

with open('alarms.txt') as f:
    alarms = f.readlines()
    for alarm in alarms:
        while Time != alarm:
            print('The time is: ' + Time)
            Time = time.strftime('%H:%M')
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if Time == alarm:
            playsound('alarm.mp3')
```

And my alarms.txt is setup like HH:MM:
18:45
18:55

Comment: Could you also show the data file

Comment: It is because you are making it so that your while cycle ends when one of the alarms goes off

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a beginner with python, how would I not end the while cycle?

Comment: share your `alarms.txt`

Comment: Added alarms.txt

Comment: Does your alarms.txt have more than 2 times included? I have run your code (with the edit from @chris below) and it works. It likely stops because your for loop concludes when you reach the final time in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information given so far, my thought is this:

Remember that readlines() reads in lines and returns strings with the newline character still trailing.
You need to compare the Time to the lines with the newline character removed.

```
import time
from playsound import playsound

Time = time.strftime('%H:%M')

with open('alarms.txt') as f:
    alarms = f.readlines()
    for alarm in alarms:
        alarm = alarm.rstrip('\n')
        while Time != alarm:
            print('The time is: ' + Time + '\n')
            Time = time.strftime('%H:%M')
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if Time == alarm:
            playsound('alarm.mp3')
```

This also assumes, of course, that the times in the text file are in the desired chronological order.